# How can I use the posterior distribution of parameters from one model in another model?

Tags: bayesian, biostatistics, stan

I would like to model different effects of siRNA treatment on measurements. Cells are grown in 384-well plates, subjected to different siRNA treatment and then imaged to determine parameters.

Around the perimeter of the 384-well plates there are mock-treated wells, which I can use for estimating spatial variations, i.e. the plate effect  $b(x,y)$. So my model for the mock-treated wells is:

$z_{mock} \sim N( b(x,y) , \sigma )$

where $b$ is the bilinear interpolation, dependent on four parameters and the coordinates $x$ and $y$. Using STAN to find the parameters of $b$ works very well.

For treated wells, I would like to estimate the treatment effect, e.g.:

$z_{treated} \sim N( b(x,y) + s_i + t_{j[i]} , \sigma )$

where $s$ and $t$ are different effects of gene $i$ or group $j[i]$. Conceptually, I would like to first model the plate effect $b$, and then use the posterior distribution of the $b$ to find $s$ and $t$. The measurements $z_{treated}$ should not influence $b$. How could I do this?

Comment: What problem do you have in implementing second part in Stan if you already have implemented the first one? It doesn't sound hard. Also, if you want any practical hints, then please post your Stan code so we have something to work on.

Comment: Your question seems to pertain to what the `cut()` function in WinBUGS attempts to do. This has been discussed in regard to Stan several times (e.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/stan-users/cut/stan-users/LIPi6yKTykc/mbdSObrSOlQJ ) and I don't think there is any way to do it directly in Stan. However, I do think (UNTESTED) it is possible to estimate both models in Stan and then do K-to-1 matching on $b$ from the second model to the first to come up with a reweighted posterior distribution for the second model that has essentially the same marginal distribution on $b$ as the first.

Comment: Thanks for the link! The linked discussion addresses (but doesn't solve) my problem: I don't want information to "flow back" from the second into the first model. I have implemented the second model, but $b$  changes because of the joint distribution.

Comment: Yes, that is why it is essentially impossible to implement `cut()` in a general Bayesian inference program like Stan because if information doesn't flow back to $b$, then it is not really Bayesian inference. What I was speculating about is if you select the values of $b$ from the second posterior distribution that match closely the values of $b$ from the first posterior distribution, then that subset of the second posterior distribution "is" what you are looking for.